# How to make FN keys work correctly?

Tags: 13.10

i am using Ubuntu 13.10 with HP envy dv7.

fn keys are not workin correctly here, like in invert option!
when i press for example f2 - id like to change name of any file its not workin, it is changin by brightness like i would press fn key with f2 and its all the same on every 'f' key.

any ideas how to make it work good??

i have installed nvidia-prime and nvidia closed drivers.